# Adding Pages In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong. I am a bit novice with Laravel, but I'm working to add new pages to an existing set up.

I have in my web.php file in the routes folder
Route::get('/page-name', [HomeController::class, 'pagename'])->name('pagename');

As far as the actual page, I've simply copied one of the existing pages and duplicated it with the new page name. However I am getting an error 500 whenever I try to load the page. I've researched how to make a new page in Laravel, but there seems to be some part of the process that I'm missing as far as "registering" the page with the routes/web.php file.

In the page itself, I definitely have the @extends and @section parts as the other pages have, as I've just copied them from another page and changed up the content.

I would appreciate any guidance on where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Consult your logs for the details of the 500 error, or set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file. (Don't do that in production, though.)

Comment: Yes this move is next while I posted for possible quick thing I could be missing. I'll return with what it says.

Comment: A 500 error just means there's some kind of PHP error. First step when you encounter one will always be consulting the logs or debug info for its cause. We can't read those logs for you.

Comment: Well aware logs can't be read by those with no access to them.
Trying to confirm if I'm not registering the new page created in some part of the Laravel framework.

I am thinking then that there is perhaps another aspect of Laravel framework that must be updated with the addition of the new page, other than creating the blade file in the directory that the page that I copied the code from (with content change, of course) came from, and in addition to updating it in the web.php file in routes.

I've started the app from scratch, but am not finding the process to a new page addition.

Comment: It's going to be a long, painful experience if you can't access your error logs. Get access, or develop locally (using the built-in `php artisan serve`, https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/valet, or https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail) so you have access.

Comment: Never said I don't have access. I'm well aware of this and use it, I don't think you read my reply. Nonetheless, I have it solved, see below if inclined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this. There is another place where the page must be registered. Aside from the web.php file in routes directory, and defining the page as

```
Route::get('/page-name', [HomeController::class, 'page'])->name('page');
```

...you also have to make a function in the app/http/controllers/HomeControllers.php file like so:

```
   /**
 * Frontend page-name admin
 * 
 */
public function page()
{
    $information = $this->metadataInformation();

    return view('page-name', compact('information'));
}
```

Of course, make the page in the resources/views directory as blade file.

The page shows up now.